# How do I optimising for loops + promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, sapui5, each

I'm developing a SAPUI5 deployed to a mobile device which is experiencing performance issues.

The below function returns a promise,
It iterates through categories and questions using underscore _each loops, 
It then performs a READ on each question in turn, before finally updating the view Model and resolving the promise.

Is there any issue with doing it this way and can it be further optimised?

```
_getAnswers: function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Loop through Categories for questions.
    _.each(oViewData.categories, function(result, index) {

      // For each Category, read Answers for each Question 
      _.each(result, function(resultInner, indexInner) {

        // Read AnswerSet on QuestionId
        surveyModel.read("/AnswerSet", {
          filters: [
            new Filter("QuestionId", FilterOperator.EQ, resultInner.QuestionId)
          ],
          success: function(oData) {
            oData.results = _.sortBy(oData.results, 'AnswerId');
            // Populate Answer Array for Question
            var oAnswersArray = [];

            _.each(oData.results, function(resultInnerInner, indexInnerInner) {
              oAnswersArray.push(resultInnerInner);
            });

            // Check what the current Answer is for the Question.
            _.each(oAnswersArray, function(answerData, answerIndex) {
              if (oViewData.categories[resultInner.CategoryId].questions[a].AnswerId === oAnswersArray[answerIndex].AnswerId) {
                oAnswersArray[answerIndex].Selected = true;
              }
            });

            // Write back the Answer Array to the viewModel
            oViewData.categories[resultInner.CategoryId].questions[a].answers = oAnswersArray;
            oViewModel.setData(oViewData);

            // Go to next Question in the Loop.
            a++;

            // resovle Promise and continue.
            resolve(true);
          },
          error: function(oError) {}
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I would try to see if you can read all the questions at once.  Issuing an async request (I assume that's what surveyModel.read does) for n "resultInners" x m "categories" would be...slow.

Comment: to me you may want to construct the model received from the backend differently - depending of course on the volume of data. You may "hang" some of the child entities off the parent entity without a call to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

In computer science there is a term called "Big O' Notation". This is used to measure the time your algorithm takes given the amount of data. In general, nested loops makes the computation time go up.

What you are doing is known as O(N^2) where each nested loop increments the exponent.

Please read this: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

If I were you, I would change how you are accessing the data and look into a better structure that does not involve nested loops.

*i.e. Don't load the items in the categories until a category is clicked.*

EDIT: 
It looks like you are returning your callback in every iteration of the second loop. This is not optimal either.

Comment: We need to load info into the Categories, because, for example, we need to determine if all the questions for the Categories have been answered etc.